# Is there a way to access the FlashBag from outside Symfony?

Tags: symfony, flash-message

I'm working in app that interacts with a Symfony app, and renders a template from the Symfony app that uses the FlashBag.  What I have so far:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag;

/*snipped code that creates a Symfony container*/

$container->enterScope('request');
$container->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
$twig = $container->get('twig');
$twig->addGlobal('app', array('session' => array('flashbag' => new FlashBag())));
echo $twig->render('AdminBundle::flashMessages.html.twig');
```

The problem is the FlashBag object I've created does not pick up the Flash messages that are in the session, so while technically the twig template does render, it never actually displays the flash messages.

An additional point of difficulty is that the outside app makes use of session, so just creating a Symfony session object also causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that all of Symfony's flash messages are stored in `$_SESSION['_sf2_flashes']`.  After I create the FlashBag, I call initialize and pass the flash messages in `$_SESSION`, like so, before adding flashBag as a global to Twig:

```
$flashMessages = isset($_SESSION['_sf2_flashes']) ? $_SESSION['_sf2_flashes'] : array();
$flash->initialize($flashMessages);
```

I also found that when done this way, the flash messages don't seem to get consumed from `$_SESSION` like when you access them the normal way, so I also had to call:

```
unset($_SESSION['_sf2_flashes']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Request::createFromGlobals() to populate your Request object. Then you can use that request object to get the flash messages.